Name of application that showed cursor coordinates (both global and local)
There was a classic Macintosh shareware/freeware application - which may have been a CDEV/INIT (control panel or extension), DA (desk accessory), or an application - that displayed both the global and local (to the window in focus) coordinates of the cursor, in a very tiny font.
The UI took the form of a small square window with no title bar. It just had a grey window border on all four sides - similar to a tiny square alert dialog. There were no buttons, nor close box.
To move the window, you could option click inside the window and move it around.
It was a "stay-on-top" window (I can't remember the correct term for that), and you could move another window behind it, without that window losing focus.
It was really useful when designing a UI and you wanted to check the co-ordinates of UI elements, relative to a window's origin.
I used this circa 1994-1997, on System 7.x.
I've searched Macintosh Repository for "location", "coordinates", "position", "mouse" and "cursor" and found nothing that resembles it, either in looks nor functionality... except for:

Corner

The search on Macintosh Garden isn't particularly good (it comes up with loads of links to threads, rather than applications), so I've not searched there much. However, having trawled through nearly 40 pages of references to "mouse" and "cursor" on Macintosh Garden, it isn't one of these either:

GetMouse4Prog
delta xy
Mouse-o-meter
ScreenRuler
"Coordinates" from Accessory Pak 1

At least, not the uploaded versions shown. Although some of them come pretty darn close.
As is clear, there are very many applications/utilities that show the global coordinates of the cursor. However, at the risk of repeating myself, I had only seen one unique application (on the Macintosh) that showed the cursor's local coordinates, relative to the origin of the top most window (the one with the current focus) -  it is this utility that I am trying to locate.
FWIW, the application would have been shareware/freeware on a Mac magazine CD-ROM (probably MacFormat, but maybe MacWorld).

Dunno, but I think it was likely reinvented several times over. I've seen such a thing on VMS (can't now recall whether VWS or DECwindows).

@dave - The thing that made this one unique was that it gave the cursor position relative to the focused local window's coordinates. All of the others that I had seen (for the Mac) just gave global coords, or a delta where you had to click and drag (like delta xy above), which can lead to inaccuracies. Or you would have to move the window to the origin of the screen.
